# Adding UITextfield as cell's accessory view

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8, uitextfield

I have 4 sections in my tableView, each section has single cell. When user selects the fourth section's cell, I want them to type on it. So I just added textfield as a accessoryView for that cell in didSelectRow function as shown below.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.section == 3 {

            //adding textField
            theTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(10, 480, 300, 40))
            theTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
            theTextField.placeholder = "Please type here...."
            theTextField.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
            theTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
            selectedCell?.accessoryView = theTextField   
        }
```

But when I click on it, the keyboard is hiding that cell. I want the table view to scroll up. Please help me to resolve this or please please let me know if there is any other way to achieve this!

[image: This is when I select the fourth cell]

[image: Table View Look like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear why you are implementing the cell specifications in "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" when a more logical place is in "cellForRowAtIndexPath". I implemented your code except putting the cell spec for section 3 in cellForRowAtIndexPath and the table cells are scrolled up as expected. See code below. To take advantage of the tableview scrolling the cell needs to be defined in cellRowForIndex. To meet your objective stated in the comment you can use the .hidden feature and insert the code as shown.

```
import UIKit
```

class: UITableViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 3 {
        selectedCell.accessoryView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
        selectedCell.accessoryView?.hidden = false
    } else {
        selectedCell.accessoryView?.hidden = true
    }

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return 4
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    if indexPath.section == 3 {

        //adding textField
        var theTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(10, 480, 300, 40))
        theTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
        theTextField.placeholder = "Please type here...."
        theTextField.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        theTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        cell.accessoryView = theTextField
        cell.accessoryView?.hidden = true
    }

    else {
        cell.textLabel!.text = "\(indexPath.section)"
    }

    return cell
}
```

}

[image: Simulator running 4S]

Comment: Thanks for reply Syed!!! I used didSelectRow func because am thinking to put an image also in a cell using cell.imageView.image  and after user selecting the cell, I want it to become textfield. That's the reason I implemented in didSelectRow func. Do you have any idea how it can be achieved??

Comment: I want to understand this. (1) In section 3, row 0 you want to put an image to start with. (2) when he user selects the row you want to display a textView. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes!!! I can do that using didSelectRow but only thing is when keyboard appears, it should get scroll up and user want to see the textfield... In my case keyboard hiding that cell. If I use for section(0) row(0), everything works fine like I need. But I want in section (3).

Comment: See my changes to original answer. Basically, to take advantage of the scrolling feature of tableview you are better off defining the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath, hide it right away, and show it when selected.

Comment: I just did as you suggested but still am facing the same problem. I don't know where am wrong. I have given space between sections very large. But Whatever it is, it should scroll right but its not working.Can you please try by adding below code and check whether its scrolling .                                                                                      func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 45 // space b/w cells
    }

Comment: I put in your code. It works fine. Check this link for screen captures: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9qqb1e0uy78aahs/AADtDhUwT8_3LeHTvRfdgcMpa?dl=0 Have you set your cells as dynamic prototypes? Do you want me to post the project?

Comment: Seriously am not understanding where am wrong. It would be really helpful if you post your project...

Comment: Here is the link to a dropbox folder https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s6dgn4jvhxwft0e/AACuGcOL6PlRXKTzHwVx7L_5a?dl=0